# CSS and Boostrap: Fitting image or carousel inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have got a series of `divs` inside `Bootstrap grid`, as these are generated dynamically it could be of any number.

Each of these `div` contains:

- Image or Carousel
- Couple of words (fit in single line, always)
- Radio buttons, these also fit in the single line.

The dimension all the `divs` are as follows:

```
width: 230px;
height: 270px;
```

I am facing a problem with Image/Carousel placement inside the `div`. I'm specifying the size of Image/Carousel to be `180px by 180px`.

But, somehow image is taking all the width of the `div` i.e. image rendering with the width of 230px, while the image's height is 180px only. See below how it is appearing.

[image]

**The desired output**: The Image/Carousel should be rendered 180*180 only. So that I can have some empty space each side.

**EXISTING CODE:**

**CSS**

```
        .nop_img {
            width:180px;
            height:180px;
        }
        .row{
            overflow: hidden; 
        }
        .nop_div {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            width: 230px;
            height: 270px;
        }
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                {% for track_id, image_path in image_urls.items %}
                {% if image_path|length == 1 %}
                <div id="nopCarousel_{{ track_id }}"  class="column nop_div">
                    {% for ip in image_path %}
                    <img class="d-block w-100 nop_img" src="{{ ip }}" >
                    {% endfor %}
                    <p>{{ image_path|length }} Face</p>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1_{{track_id}}" value="option1" checked>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                act1
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2_{{track_id}}" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                                act2
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3_{{track_id}}" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                                act3
                            </label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div id="nopCarousel_{{ track_id }}" class="carousel slide column nop_div" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- <div id="nopCarousel_{{ track_id }}" class="carousel slide column nop_div" data-ride=False data-interval=500> -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            {% for ip in image_path %}
                            <!-- <h1> Index: {{ forloop.counter }}</h1> -->
                            {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100 nop_img" src="{{ ip }}" >
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100 nop_img" src="{{ ip }}" >
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#nopCarousel_{{ track_id }}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#nopCarousel_{{ track_id }}" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                        <p>{{ image_path|length }} Faces</p>
                        <!-- Radio button -- Can give dropdown too -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1_{{track_id}}" value="option1" checked>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                act1
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2_{{track_id}}" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                                act2
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3_{{track_id}}" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                                act3
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you able to try with max-width: XXXpx and width:100% instead of just width (for the image style rule)?

Comment: Thanks, I can give it a go. I will let you know here.

Comment: do you want to make the image not to stretch but it should stay in its actual height and width?

Comment: I want the complete image, not cropped. But it should be always consistent 180*180. So I guess smaller images would be stretched while larger one should be shrunk. I think so...

Comment: It worked @alpharomeo. If you can write as an answer, I would accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your image rules to include max-width:180px; and width:100%;

More information if interested: https://blog.prototypr.io/what-even-is-the-difference-between-width-and-max-width-8f37b282c7f1

Comment: @downvoter - if this answer is incorrect / needs revision - please explain why (so that we may learn!) It helped the OP and that is what matters!

Comment: Probably cause your answer says how but not why. A link to why is not an answer on SO. Edit your question to explain why your solution solves the problem.

Comment: It worked for me, hence upvoted it. Someone downvoted the question too